# Googleアナリティクス（GA4）で、レポートのユーザー数とカスタムのユーザー数に差異が発生する

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics

Googleアナリティクス（GA4）にて、解析レポートを見る際、「ユーザー属性→概要」からいつものように表で【地域別ユーザー数】を見ていました。（Sendai...Sapporo...と市区町村別のものです。）

これを、10位までの棒グラフにしようと思い、「カスタム」から作成したところ、これまでのデータと数が合わないのです。ユーザー属性から見るデータと比べて、同じ月でも1ヶ月に20ユーザーぐらい増えたり減ったりします。ちゃんと値を「総ユーザー数」に設定しているのに何故でしょうか？

セグメント＝なし
行＝市区町村
列＝10
値＝総ユーザー数

とカスタムしています。

これはGoogleアナリティクスの、何かしらの誤差の範囲内なのでしょうか？ご回答のほど、よろしくお願い致します。